# Custom Hindi Keyboard

Tags: android, xml, keyboard, android-input-method

I am working on an `Android` project.Project is to develop a `Hindi` android keyboard. I have seen many tutorials and articles regarding development of Custom Soft Keyboards. I have also made a keyboard(English) using [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) tutorial and it is working just fine. Now I thought that for `Hindi` (or any other language for that matter) I have to change the locale name in `method.xml` file and `android:codes` & `android:keylabel` tags in `qwerty.xml` file. But I am stuck now because I can't find the codes(ASCII or whatever should be used) for `Hindi` alphabets. Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is my `method.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <subtype
        android:label="@string/subtype_hi_IN"
        android:imeSubtypeLocale="hi_IN"
        android:imeSubtypeMode="keyboard" />
</input-method>
```

This is my `qwerty.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="60dp">
     <Row>
    <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
    <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
    <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
    <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
    <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"/>
    <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
    <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
    <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
    <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
        <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
        <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
        <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
        <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
        <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
        <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
        <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
        <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="97"  android:keyLabel="a" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="115" android:keyLabel="s"/>
        <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="d"/>
        <Key android:codes="102" android:keyLabel="f"/>
        <Key android:codes="103" android:keyLabel="g"/>
        <Key android:codes="104" android:keyLabel="h"/>
        <Key android:codes="106" android:keyLabel="j"/>
        <Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="k"/>
        <Key android:codes="108" android:keyLabel="l"/>
        <Key android:codes="35,64" android:keyLabel="\# \@" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-1" android:keyLabel="CAPS" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="122" android:keyLabel="z"/>
        <Key android:codes="120" android:keyLabel="x"/>
        <Key android:codes="99" android:keyLabel="c"/>
        <Key android:codes="118" android:keyLabel="v"/>
        <Key android:codes="98" android:keyLabel="b"/>
        <Key android:codes="110" android:keyLabel="n"/>
        <Key android:codes="109" android:keyLabel="m"/>
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="."/>
        <Key android:codes="63,33,58" android:keyLabel="\? ! :" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key android:codes="44" android:keyLabel="," android:keyWidth="10%p"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="SPACE" android:keyWidth="40%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyLabel="DEL" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyLabel="DONE" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Comment: Have you find the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0900-097F) is the link for `Unicodes` for `Devanagri`.Use those codes as following:

```
<Row>
                <Key android:codes="0x0905" android:keyLabel="अ" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
                <Key android:codes="0x0906" android:keyLabel="आ"/>
                <Key android:codes="0x0907" android:keyLabel="इ"/>
                <Key android:codes="0x0908" android:keyLabel="ई"/>
                <Key android:codes="0x0909" android:keyLabel="उ"/>
                <Key android:codes="0x090A" android:keyLabel="ऊ"/>
                <Key android:codes="0x090F" android:keyLabel="ए"/>
                <Key android:codes="0x0910" android:keyLabel="ऐ"/>
                <Key android:codes="0x0913" android:keyLabel="ओ"/>
                <Key android:codes="0x0914" android:keyLabel="औ" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
            </Row>
```